# Make Asymptote read YAML or JSON files

Tags: diagrams, asymptote, json

I often write my data-files from simulations written in Python or C++ in json on yaml files. I recently heard about the [asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/) software which can be used for really 2d and 3d plotting.

Is it possible to make asymptote read YAML or JSON files? From the manual, it seems that it can only read .csv or .xdr (External Data Representation) files. While for many purposes .csv should be good enough, for morre sophisiticated output files with lots of structure, I would need YAML or JSON.

Are there any modules out there which do this? I know Python has very nice YAML parsers (which is what I've traditionally used, along with Matplotlib for plotting). Something for Asymptote would be great, since the resulting graphics are much more slick that gnuplot or Matplotlib,

Comment: You could try to use an Asymptote library for Python, e.g., http://emmett.ca/PyAsy/examples.html.